# Click Event on div, but not on elements inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which should toggle a checkbox when clicked.
But inside my div, I also have some more input-fields, which shouldn't toggle this checkbox.

I tried adding off and unbind on the class of these inputs/labels but they still toggle the original checkbox.
Also, `e.stopPropagation()` doesn't disable the toggle.

```
<div class="ui centered raised card itemSelector" id="AJ-HUB">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header"><label><input type="checkbox" name="HUB" value="AJ-HUB"  class="HUB">AJAX Hub</label></div>
      <div class="description"><p>Description Text</p></div> 
      <div class="extra content">
        <p><label  class="noSelectorClick"><input type="radio" name="AJ-HUB_col" value="Wit"  disabled >Wit</label></p>
        <p><label  class="noSelectorClick"><input type="radio" name="AJ-HUB_col" value="Zwart" checked disabled >Zwart</label></p>                                                                               
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    $('.itemSelector').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        let input = $('#wizard .header input[value=' + this.id + ']')
        let isChecked = input.is(':checked')
        if(isChecked == true) {
            input.prop('checked',false)
        } else {
            input.prop('checked',true)
        }

    })\\.children('.noSelectorClick').off()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the clicked instance is the same as the one you registered the click event on.

```
$('.itemSelector').on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target !== this) {
            return;
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        let input = $('#wizard .header input[value=' + this.id + ']')
        let isChecked = input.is(':checked')
        if(isChecked == true) {
            input.prop('checked',false)
        } else {
            input.prop('checked',true)
        }

    })
```